# Evaluate column of matrix

Tags: r, matrix, ggplot2

I am trying to evaluate the 8th column of a matrix

```
sep <- read.csv("California_SEP_assets_csv.csv")
Sub1 <- sep[grep("SEP.11", names(sep))]
sep$newCol <- 100*rowSums(Sub1)/rowSums(sep[4:7])
library(sp)
coords <- cbind(Longitude = as.numeric(as.character(sep$Longitude)),Latitude=as.numeric(as.character(sep$Latitude)))

if (sep[8] > 50){
  sep.pts <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords,sep[,-(2:3)],proj4string = CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
} else  {
  sep2.pts <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords,sep[,-(2:3)],proj4string = CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
}
```

I get warning

```
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

What is the syntax to evaluate each each entry under a single column?

Here is the matrix

```
dput(head(sep))
structure(list(Site = structure(1:6, .Label = c("31R001", "31R002", 
"31R003", "31R004", "31R005", "31R006", "31R007", "31R008", "31R011", 
"31R013", "31R014", "31R016", "31R018", "31R019", "31R020", "31R021", 
"31R022", "31R023", "31R024", "31R025", "31R026", "31R027", "31R029", 
"31R030", "31R031", "31R032", "31R034", "31R035", "31R036", "31R038", 
"31R039", "31R040", "31R041", "31R042", "31R043", "31R044", "31R045", 
"31R046", "31R048", "31R049", "31R050", "31R051", "31R052", "31R053", 
"31R054", "31R055", "31R056", "31R057", "31R058", "31R059", "31R060", 
"31R061", "31R069", "31R071", "31R072", "31R075", "31R435", "31R440", 
"31R445", "31R450", "31R455", "31R460", "31R470", "31R600", "31R722", 
"31R801", "31R825", "31R826", "31R829", "31R840", "31R843", "31R861", 
"31R880"), class = "factor"), Latitude = c(33.808874, 33.877256, 
33.820825, 33.852373, 33.829697, 33.810274), Longitude = c(-117.844048, 
-117.700135, -117.811845, -117.795516, -117.787532, -117.830429
), Windows.SEP.11 = c(63L, 174L, 11L, 85L, 163L, 71L), Mac.SEP.11 = c(0L, 
1L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 50L), Windows.SEP.12 = c(124L, 185L, 9L, 75L, 
23L, 5L), Mac.SEP.12 = c(0L, 1L, 32L, 1L, 0L, 50L), newCol = c(33.6898395721925, 
48.4764542936288, 26.7857142857143, 52.7950310559006, 87.6344086021505, 
68.75)), .Names = c("Site", "Latitude", "Longitude", "Windows.SEP.11", 
"Mac.SEP.11", "Windows.SEP.12", "Mac.SEP.12", "newCol"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Eventually, I'd like to color-code plots on Google map where the ones that are `>= 50` are red, and `< 50%` are green

## More Info

My original code gave only red points, regardless

```
library(ggmap)
setwd("d:/GIS/31R")
sep <- read.csv("California_SEP_assets_csv.csv")
library(sp)
coords <- cbind(Longitude = as.numeric(as.character(sep$Longitude)),Latitude=as.numeric(as.character(sep$Latitude)))
sep.pts <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords,sep[,-(2:3)],proj4string = CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
plot(sep.pts, pch=".",col="darkred")
map <- qmap('Yorba Linda', zoom = 11, maptype = 'hybrid')
map + geom_point(data=sep, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude), color="red", size = 5, alpha = 0.5)
```

Which gave

[image]

## Another Update

I changed code to remove `,-(2:3)` from SpatialPointsDataFrame. I really don't understand the significance of removing the longitude and latitude columns, but at least it doesn't give error.

However, I am researching how to plot SpatialPointsDataFrame on a map.

Here is the code so far

```
library(ggmap)
setwd("d:/GIS/31R")
sep <- read.csv("California_SEP_assets_csv.csv")
Sub1 <- sep[grep("SEP.11", names(sep))]
sep$newCol <- 100*rowSums(Sub1)/rowSums(sep[4:7])
library(sp)
coords <- cbind(Longitude = as.numeric(as.character(sep$Longitude)),Latitude=as.numeric(as.character(sep$Latitude)))


sep.pts <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords,sep[sep.pts$newCol >= 50], proj4string = CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
sep2.pts <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords,sep[sep.pts$newCol < 50], proj4string = CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))

map <- qmap('Yorba Linda', zoom = 11, maptype = 'hybrid')
map + geom_point(data=sep.pts, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude), color="red", size = 5, alpha = 0.5) + geom_point(data=sep2.pts, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude), color="green", size = 5, alpha = 0.5)
```

and it gives error

`Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class SpatialPointsDataFrame`

Comment: `sep[8] > 50` will check every row of the 8th column.  And return a TRUE or FALSE for every check. The `if` statement is expecting one TRUE or FALSE value. You are giving it many logical values. Consider rewriting without the if statement. Clarify your meaning of that conditional please. Would you like to check each row? Or are you testing the length of sep[8]?

Comment: @plafort I'll update the original question soon

Comment: I see your other questions on here. I think I see where your going. You want two different data frames? One with the 50 or greater, and under 50 in the other?

Comment: @plafort Correct. And I'd like to plot it on a geographical map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ggplot2 is not my specialty but the structure of implied conditionals goes like this:

If I had a data frame of `df <- data.frame(x=1:3, y=4:6)`.

```
df
  x y
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6
```

I could create two data frames for values of x greater than one and those that are not. I want it to look like this:

```
df1
  x y
1 1 4

df2
  x y
2 2 5
3 3 6
```

I could get there with:

```
split(df, df$x > 1)
$`FALSE`
  x y
1 1 4

$`TRUE`
  x y
2 2 5
3 3 6
```

Update -

We can assign the function to a variable.

```
lst <- split(df, df$x > 1)
df1 <- lst[[1]]
df2 <- lst[[2]]
```

In your case,

```
lst <- split(sep, sep[,8] >= 50)
under50 <- lst[[1]]
over50 <- lst[[2]]
```

Comment: R is pretty new to me. I'll try to incorporate this type of logic.

Comment: How to I save the output to two difference vectors, i.e. one where column is >= 50 and other where < 50?

Comment: Thank you! I'll work from here to see if I can plot color-coded data

Comment: @plaform This answers my question. May open another thread if another doubt arises.

Answer (score 1):

```
sep.pts <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords,sep[sep.pts$newCol >= 50, -(2:3)],proj4string = CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
sep2.pts <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords,sep[sep.pts$newCol < 50,-(2:3)],proj4string = CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
```

I'm assuming per your last line you wanted >= and < 50 rather than > and <=.

You need to pass your logical vector as the first argument to the subset operator as shown here.

Comment: I get error `Error in validObject(.Object) : 
  invalid class “SpatialPointsDataFrame” object: number of rows in data.frame and SpatialPoints don't match`